# unable to understand syntax of Action method in Play

Tags: scala, playframework

How could I pass a block of code (instead of parenthesis) to `Action`? I am unable to understand this syntax. Shouldn't I use `()`

```
val echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

I suppose `Action` is `Function1`. The following example from Scala, uses `()`, so how `Action` works with `{}`

```
object Main extends App {
   val succ = (x: Int) => x + 1 //create Function 1
   val anonfun1 = new Function1[Int, Int] { //create another Function1
     def apply(x: Int): Int = x + 1
   }
   assert(succ(0) == anonfun1(0)) //notice use of ()
}
```

I later tested using `()` instead of `{}` and the code still works. So is the use of `{}` to only improve readability?

```
val echo = Action ( request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion about Play framework's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664675/confusion-about-play-frameworks-code)

Comment: Please first read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaActions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala parentheses and curly braces are interchangeable in various scenarios one of them being the wrapper `()` in a function`s argument list.

```scala
def multiply(num: Int)(by: Int): Int = num * by

multiply(5)(2)
multiply{5}{2}
```

the curly braces syntax also allows for multi line expressions to be written inside:

```scala
multiply{
  val num = 5
  num
}{
  val by = 2
  by
}
```

Comment: parentheses and curly braces are `NOT` interchangeable in Scala in any scenarios. It is because Scala provided multiple ways to write same things.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to read more about Scala.

Lets first begin with basics,

```
scala> val a = 5
// a: Int = 5
```

Here, the RHS is just `5` and is called a `expression eiteral` or a `literal expression`.

Similarly, Scala also allows,

```
scala> val a = { 5 }
// a: Int = 5
```

Here, the RHS is `{ 5 }` and is called a `block expression` and this `block` here evaluates to `5`.

Now, let move on to a our use case

```
scala> object A {
     |   def apply(i: Int) = i + 5
     | }
// defined module A
```

Now, Scala allows us to use this `A` in two ways,

```
val x1 = A(10)
// x1: Int = 15

// Or
val x2 = A { 10 }
// x2: Int = 15
```

Why ? Take a look at Scala Language Specification - [Functional Application](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#function-applications)

Here, you will see following grammer,

```
SimpleExpr    ::=  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
ArgumentExprs ::=  ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’
                |  ‘(’ [Exprs ‘,’] PostfixExpr ‘:’ ‘_’ ‘*’ ‘)’
                |  [nl] BlockExpr
Exprs         ::=  Expr {‘,’ Expr}
```

So, if we use `(` and `)` to apply a function then we can provide any `Expr` (even multiple) otherwise we have to provide a `BlockExpr`

Now, lets talk about your example (simplified for explanation),

```
val echo = Action( request => Ok("") )

// VS

val echo = Action { request => Ok("") }
```

The difference exist in how it gets parsed by the parser.

The parsing for first one proceeds with the following rules,

```
SimpleExpr        ::=  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
ArgumentExprs     ::=  ‘(’ [Exprs] ‘)’
Exprs             ::=  Expr {‘,’ Expr}
Expr              ::=  (Bindings | [‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘=>’ Expr
```

Where second one uses the following rules,

```
SimpleExpr        ::=  SimpleExpr1 ArgumentExprs
ArgumentExprs     ::=  [nl] BlockExpr
BlockExpr         ::=  ‘{’ Block ‘}’
Block             ::=  BlockStat {semi BlockStat} [ResultExpr]
ResultExpr        ::=  (Bindings | ([‘implicit’] id | ‘_’) ‘:’ CompoundType) ‘=>’ Block
Block             ::=  BlockStat {semi BlockStat} [ResultExpr]
BlockStat         ::=  Expr1
```

Full parse-tree expressions,

[image]